# How to get last modified date of a file in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, metadata, last-modified

[This guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate) on the Python library says `cloudstorage.stat()` returns

> ... last-modified time, header-length, content type for the specified file.

The [Java guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate) however, seems to have no counterpart. At least, I cannot find it in [GcsFileMetadata](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsFileMetadata).

Is it possible to get this information using the Java library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Java library doesn't have this feature (yet).

You can set this info manually, though:

```
GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
  .setBucket("my_bucket") 
  .setKey("my_object")
  .setAcl("public-read")
  .setMimeType("text/html") //etc etc
  .setUserMetadata("date-created", "01/09/2011", "owner", "Jon");
```

And retrieve this piece of metadata with

```
GcsFileMetadata.getOptions().getUserMetadata().get("date-created")
```

Comment: Bit late here, any chance you happen to know if this has been implemented now?